# How to disable loopback interface in Linux (Fedora)?

Tags: linux, networking, loopback, network-interface, loopback-address

So that requests to `localhost` are treated as if coming from remote host in LAN?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating your `/etc/hosts` file, replacing:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

With your actual IP address? e.g.,

```
192.168.0.42    localhost
```

(This doesn't actually disable the loopback address, you can still connect to `127.0.0.1`, but connecting to `localhost` should come in through your network interface, which I believe is what you're asking)

Comment: Not what I want, it want it to be the same even if you visit `127.0.0.1`.